# error in calling a method in the same class

Tags: java

i tried compiling this basic code and can't get my main method to call another method. From my understanding, I don't have to create an object because both methods are in the same class.

However, it gives me the error- java: '.class' expected - when i call my method. anyone know why:

```
    public class Main {
        double x=0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Function(double x);

        }
        public static double Function(double x) {
            x+=5;
            return x;

        }
        }
```

Comment: Use camelcase names for methods, starting lower-case. Java is not `C#` or `VB.NET`

Answer (score 1):

Look what you are doing in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function(double x);
}
```

you are calling a method like `Function(double x);` but that is not correct, remove the type `double`, then you need to make the variable x ***static***, because you are in an static context, after that just pass the argument `x` as parameter;

like:

```
static double x = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function(x);
}
```

---

Option2 is getting rid off static things and use instances...

```
class Main {
    double x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.function(m.x);
    }

    public double function(double x) {
        x += 5;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: `x` is not static, so can't be used from the static context.

Answer (score 0):

Non static variables can't be called from a static method. So call it by creating object of class in which the variable is declared.

```
public class Main {
    double x=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Main mm=new Main();  //Creating Object of Class
         Function(mm.x);      //pass the value with object.var
    }
    public static double Function(double x) {
        x+=5;
        return x;
    }
}
```